# Creating module on vTiger 5.2.0

Tags: module, crm, vtiger

I can't find documentation for creating modules in vTiger. Where can I find doc. Please share with link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Creating_New_Module

Answer (score 0):

I have also used this software and it works very well. Other than that reading around the vtlib functionality to massage new components into place is advised. :)

https://www.vtiger.com/crm-utilities/vtdziner-11-beta/